# Maps for JVectorMap?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, dictionary, svg, jvectormap

I'm trying to create a global map which I can click on a country and redirect to another map, this is, the map of that country I clicked on. I know how to do this, but I don't know where I can get the maps of all countries or how can I create this maps. I only got maps of United States and Germany.
Thanks in advance.!

Comment: any luck with this? I'm interested in something similar

Comment: Is the question related to how to add maps that don't exist?

Answer (score 0):

More maps are available from the new jVectorMap site [jvectormap.com](http://jvectormap.com).

Answer (score 0):

here you can find several maps: http://jvectormap.com/maps/world/europe/

**World**
Europe
Whole World

**Countries**
Argentina
Australia
Austria
Belgium
Canada
China
Colombia
Denmark
France
Germany
India
Italy
Netherlands
New Zealand
Norway
Philippines
Poland
Portugal
South Africa
Spain
Sweden
Switzerland
Thailand Regions
Thailand
United Kingdom
USA
Venezuela

**Cities**
Chicago
New York City